# How to use bottomnavigationbar in flutter with Getx state management?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

When I use obx for bottom navigation bar, I take error.How to use bottomnavigationbar in flutter with Getx state management?

Comment: Can you show us some code snippets?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Checkout my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: '/home',
    defaultTransition: Transition.fade,
    getPages: [
      GetPage(
        name: '/home',
        page: () => HomePage(),
        binding: HomeBinding(),
      ),
      GetPage(
        name: '/another',
        page: () => AnotherPage(),
      ),
    ],
  ));
}

class HomeBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => HomeController());
  }
}

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  static HomeController get to => Get.find();

  var currentIndex = 0.obs;

  final pages = <String>['/browse', '/history', '/settings'];

  void changePage(int index) {
    currentIndex.value = index;
    Get.toNamed(pages[index], id: 1);
  }

  Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    if (settings.name == '/browse')
      return GetPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        page: () => BrowsePage(),
        binding: BrowseBinding(),
      );

    if (settings.name == '/history')
      return GetPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        page: () => HistoryPage(),
        binding: HistoryBinding(),
      );

    if (settings.name == '/settings')
      return GetPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        page: () => SettingsPage(),
        binding: SettingsBinding(),
      );

    return null;
  }
}

class HomePage extends GetView<HomeController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Navigator(
        key: Get.nestedKey(1),
        initialRoute: '/browse',
        onGenerateRoute: controller.onGenerateRoute,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx(
        () => BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: 'Browse',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.history),
              label: 'History',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: 'Settings',
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: controller.currentIndex.value,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.pink,
          onTap: controller.changePage,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BrowsePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Browse')),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(Get.find<BrowseController>().title.value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HistoryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('History')),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(Get.find<HistoryController>().title.value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Settings')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text(Get.find<SettingsController>().title.value),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Another Page'),
              onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/another'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BrowseController extends GetxController {
  final title = 'Browser'.obs;
}

class HistoryController extends GetxController {
  final title = 'History'.obs;
}

class SettingsController extends GetxController {
  final title = 'Settings'.obs;
}

class BrowseBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => BrowseController());
  }
}

class HistoryBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => HistoryController());
  }
}

class SettingsBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => SettingsController());
  }
}

class AnotherPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Another Page')), body: Container());
  }
}
```